# trouble with passing values between functions

Tags: javascript, events, properties, parameters

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass values from one function to another. I've created a program where I create boxes using values from a form that show up in the webpage. The values I'm talking about are property values of the boxes themselves.

Here is the function where the values are assigned to the boxes:

```
function addBox(newbox) {  
       for (var i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) { 
       counter++;
       var id = counter;                          
       var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
       var div = document.createElement("div"); 
       div.value = id;
       console.log(div.value);                  
       div.className += " " + "box"; 
       div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
       div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color; 
       var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
       var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
       div.style.left = x + "px";
       div.style.top = y + "px"; 
       scene.appendChild(div); 
       div.onclick = display;              
        }                      
      }
```

Here is the function that I'm having trouble passing the values to. I need to pass them so that I can display them in an alert box when I click on each box:

```
  function display(e) {
  alert(e.target.toSource());
  }
```

So far when I click it, I just get an empty pair of brackets in the alert box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your example in JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jCC6n/

I'm seeing at least two problems.

1. "counter" is undefined, which causes the code to fail when it first attempt to increment it. I added a variable declaration at the top of the function.
2. toSource is undefined. I replaced that with "outerHTML", which works in Chrome, IE and presumably other browsers.

With the above changes, this worked.

```
function display(e) {
    alert(e.target.outerHTML);
}

function addBox(newbox) {  
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) { 
        counter++;
        var id = counter;                          
        var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
        var div = document.createElement("div"); 
        div.value = id;
        div.className += " " + "box"; 
        div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
        div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color; 
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
        //div.style.left = x + "px";
        //div.style.top = y + "px"; 
        scene.appendChild(div); 
        div.onclick = display;              
    }                      
}

addBox({ number: 3, name: "Hello", color: '#C00' });
```

Be advised that event handling using onclick event handlers varies from browser to browser. It will be best to use a JavaScript framework that knows all the differences and gives you a unified way to handle events. jQuery is arguably the most used such framework.